# Rake Boards & Rake Cladding

Tags: roof, roofing, gutters, fascia

What is the proper term roofers use for rake board cladding, as opposed to fascia board or fascia wrap?

What should rake board cladding be called on a roofer's estimate or roofer's contract if it is to be all replaced?